# Autodesk Forge messed up view

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We are using the Autodesk Forge model derivative and viewer API's for sharing Revit models with our customers. 
This works very well for almost all our Revit models. But currently we have 2 Revit models which use the same template, and with those 2 models the Forge viewer does not render these correct. It looks like we get some kind of exploded view, materials are not on the correct place etc (see images).

We assume it has something to do with the Revit template, but we cannot find it. Any suggestions?

Revit
[image]

Forge
[image]

Comment: a quick question: is this model linking with some other models, or standalone? From the snapshot, it looks the the missing elements should belong to one model, but it is weird they are gone. If you could provided a small demo model, we can diagnose what happened with the case. Please email us at forge.help@autodesk.com with private data.

Comment: The model is not linked to any other model. It looks like the elements are not missing, but placed on another location. Just like an exploded view. I will try to send the project by email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround, it looks like the problem was the cars which I was using in the model. These were Revit families where a DWG import was used. 
When removing the cars from the model all other materials where rendering fine in the Forge Viewer. I sended the model also to Forge support and hoping for a solution so I can use the cars again.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, on Revit, go to [publish settings](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Revit-CAR/files/GUID-09FBF9E2-6ECF-447D-8FA8-12AB16495BC3-htm.html) and confirm the **names** of the 3D selected to be extracted. On Viewer, ensure you're showing the same view, you can see the name where you load a specific viewable.

Comment: Renamed my 3d view and uploaded again, but unfortunately the view is still messed up.

Comment: If this 3d view is not chosen in the "set" of the publish setting, despite renaming, Forge Revit extractor will still use the default `{3D}` view while translating. So, please check if this view is in your publish setting sets.